# Dart ClassMirror newInstance method says no such constructor

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I tried to dynamically create a new instance of a class like this:

```dart
this.componentClass.newInstance(new Symbol(''), [this, el]).reflectee;
```

The class reflected in this.componentClass is called `ButtonComponent` and it is a subclass of Component. When running a test on this, I get an error:

```dart
Test failed: Caught No constructor 'ButtonComponent.' declared in class 'ButtonComponent'.
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'ButtonComponent.'
Receiver: Type: class 'ButtonComponent' Arguments: [...]
```

There are default constructors in both Component and ButtonComponent classes. Here is the code, to make sure I didn't miss anything:

```dart
class Component {

  Element  element ;
  Template template;

  Component(this.template, this.element) {
    this.element.replaceWith(new Element.html(template.html));
  }

}

class ButtonComponent extends Component {

  ButtonComponent(template, element) : super(template, element) {};

}
```

Any ideas what is wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a similar test in 1.0.0.3_r30187 and I don't get this error. If you don't use the last stable version of Dart you should update your version.

Here's my tested code :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Component {
  Element  element ;

  Component(this.element) {
    this.element.children.add(new Element.html("<b>Dart rocks</b>"));
  }
}

class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  ButtonComponent(element) : super(element);
}

main() {
  final a = reflectClass(ButtonComponent).newInstance(new Symbol(''), 
      [document.documentElement]).reflectee;
  print(a); // display : Instance of 'ButtonComponent'
}
```

Comment: I'm running even newer version, 1.0.0.3_r30188. It was installed along wiyh Dartium from an ubuntu package. How do I check which version Dartium uses (I run my tests in the browser not command line)? Anyway, thanks for checking it for me. Maybe I should seek a typo somewhere deeper in my code.

Comment: I tested in Dartium and dart2js. You can try my test to check if your Dart SDK works correctly.

Comment: The problem appears to be inheritance. If I remove `extend Component` and call to `super` in constructor then it works. I don't understand why.

Comment: Your code also works. Thank you, will keep looking what's wrong.